# Jquery image path not changing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a jquery ajax carousel and I am trying to edit the path, but what ever I do with it, it's not changing up. Can any one please help me out with this.

Here is the jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function () {


var dir = "../images/big-carousel/";
var first = true;
var className = 'class="item active"';
var fileextension = ".jpg";
$.ajax({
    url: dir,
    success: function (data) {
        $(data).find("a:contains(" + fileextension + ")").each(function () {

            if (first == false) {
                className = 'class="item"';
            }
            var filename = this.href.replace(window.location.host, "").replace("http:///tabs/", "");


    $("#bigCarousel .carousel-inner").append($("<div " + className + " style=\"background-image:url(" + filename + dir + ")\"></div>"));

            first = true;
        });
    }
```

HTML Code

```
<div id="background-carousel">
            <div id="bigCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                <div class="carousel-inner" >
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: can you add code in jsfiddle?

Comment: `filename + dir` doesn't look correct as you would have `../images/big-carousel/` appended after your filename.  also is there an extra slash in this: `http:///tabs/`.  Does your item div have any height set?  If not it will be height 0 as there is nothing in it which may also be a reason for it not to work

Comment: If you inspect carousel-inner, can you copy the html that is generated and post it in your question.  Also if you remove the host won't you be left with http://

Comment: <div style="background-image:url(http://localhost/webgaff/tabs/1.jpg)" class="item"></div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this code:

```
$("#bigCarousel .carousel-inner").append($("<div " + className + " style=\"background-image:url(" + dir + filename + ")\"></div>"));
```

Answer (score -1):

try to replace you last line jquery code with following :-

```
$("#bigCarousel .carousel-inner").append($("<div " + className + " style=\"background-image:url('" + filename + dir + "')\"></div>"));
```

It may help you.